# I add the query string on Url but the Url not exchange

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, cherrypy

This is a server in Cherrypy that I programmed and I want add the query string.

But when I use the redirect the site and it appears that does not work with the `localhost:8080/index?foo=1&foo=2`
Why?

My project

```
import cherrypy
import urllib
#import requests

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        jsondict = [('foo', '1'), ('foo', '2')]
        p = urllib.urlencode(jsondict)
        #url = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080?%s" % params)
        #urlVar = 1
        #urlVar2 = 2
        #requests.get("localhost:8080/?", params =p)

        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("localhost:8080/index?" + p)

cherrypy.config.update({

        'server.socketPort': 8080

})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

But I want add the variable  on the Url while the site's starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs you must not specify host and also you need to have a view that handles your query parameters, so do something like this:

```
class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, foo=None):
        if not foo:
            jsondict = [('foo', '1'), ('foo', '2')]
            p = urllib.urlencode(jsondict)
            #url = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080?%s" % params)
            #urlVar = 1
            #urlVar2 = 2
            #requests.get("localhost:8080/?", params =p)

            raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/index?" + p)

        return foo
```

Comment: GooD!!!!
404 Not Found

Unexpected query string parameters: foo, fo

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 40, in __call__
    raise sys.exc_info()[1]
HTTPError: (404, 'Unexpected query string parameters: foo, fo')

Why now this error?

Comment: Because your index handler/view does not accept any parameters. Read the docs to see how to define a view with parameters.

Comment: exactly but can I have some advice?

Comment: And other question this HTTPRedirect is using a redirect aways?

Comment: See the edit for advice. In your original version yes, the view always redirected to itself.

Comment: ok I find the solution for Unexpected query string parameters but now I have problem that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Now I open the new question

Comment: See my example, it works ok without going into redirect loop.

Comment: Perfect Thx    I vote all comment for you have too much point